# Proving that $f: N\times N \rightarrow N$ is surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble proving that the function $$f: N\times N \rightarrow N, \ \ f(i,j)=2^{i-1}(2j-1)$$ is surjective.

Work: I know that using the theorem in which $n$ is the product of prime numbers play an important role. For instance, $n=2^{i-1}p$, $p$ is the product of all prime factors of $n$. However, from here I don't know how to proceed. What makes it difficult for me is that how am I suppose to find an arbitrary $n\in N$ such that $f(i,j)=n$?

Comment: You have all the "even" part of $n=2^{i-1}p$ in $2^{i-1}$, so $p$ is odd since is the product of primes greater than 2. Since $p$ is odd, it must be of the form $2j-1$ for some natural number $j$ (namely $\frac{p+1}{2}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n\in\Bbb N$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $n=2^m\cdot k$ where $k$ is odd and $m\geq 0$. But now $$f\left(m+1,\frac{k-1}{2}\right)=n$$ so $f$ is surjective.